# Send mail with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm asking almost the same question again but I still didn't find how I can resolve my problem. I want to send a mail to all my user when an article is published. I think I've set up ActionMailer successfully because I use MailCatcher to see if the mail goes and I catch the mail correctly but the mail do not arrive inbox.

**Development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
user_name:            'mailaxessrails@gmail.com',
password:             '********',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

**Source from MailCatcher**

```
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 07:39:44 -0700
From: mailaxessrails@gmail.com
To: contact@******.com
Message-ID: <5575a930a739c_f723f9271aa20c432045@localhost.localdomain.mail>
Subject: **TEST**
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_5575a930a3eb8_f723f9271aa20c4319c";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_5575a930a3eb8_f723f9271aa20c4319c
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

*******************************
===============================================

----==_mimepart_5575a930a3eb8_f723f9271aa20c4319c
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>oooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  </body>
</html>

  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_5575a930a3eb8_f723f9271aa20c4319c--
```

I really don't know how to resolve this, I got no error but it doesn't work. How can I do to make it work ?

Comment: I am not sure, but other than configuration related to action mailer, check for Application-specific password, in my case gmail was not allowing mails to send without generating Application specific password. you can find more information [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270)

Answer (score 1):

You missing the `default_url_options`, Here the [Reference](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  user_name:            'mailaxessrails@gmail.com',
  password:             '********',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  
}
```